# snapshot never shows null even if there is no data in it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, error-handling, flutter-layout

I am facing the error that the snapshot inside the stream builder never shows `null`, even though there is no data in it.

**I have printed the values of the `snapshot.data` / `snapshot.hasData` but once I run it, it shows null/false but just within minutes it starts showing not `null` / `true`**

Maybe the error is because of the using Stream Builder or something else Can you please help if you got the solution or what alternative you have used for this:

The full code is here : [Accounts.Dart](https://github.com/sheikh-tabarak/account-book/blob/main/lib/Screens/Accounts/Accounts.dart)

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Accountforuser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          print('Here is test data ' +
// snapshot.hasData.toString());
// snapshot.hasData);
// snapshot.isEmpty);
 snapshot.data=null);

          if(snapshot.stackTrace.toString()==null){
           isLoading=false;
           return Text('No Data');
          }
else{
< Here is Data>
}
```

I was curious about using this

```
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)
```

But don't know.

I have printed the values of `snapshot.data` / `snapshot.hasData` but once I run, it shows null/false but just within minutes it starts showing not null/true.

I am expecting the solution or an alternative to using `Streambuilder` or the `QuerySnapshot`

Answer (score 1):

from the official [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot):

> A DocumentSnapshot is returned from a query, or by accessing the document directly. Even if no document exists in the database, a snapshot will always be returned.

so the snapshot will never be `null` even if no document is there, but you can check over them with the `exists` like this:

```
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return Text("Document does exist");
    } else {
      return Text("Document does not exist");
    }
```

so in your case, you can replace :

```
     if(snapshot.stackTrace.toString()==null){
       isLoading=false;
       return Text('No Data');
      }
```

with:

```
      if(!snapshot.data!.exists){
       isLoading=false;
       return Text('No Data');
      }
```

Comment: I have tried all of these, it just shows null in start and then not null later

Comment: @SheikhTabarak "I have tried all of these" is hard to help with unless you show us what you did with the code that Gwhyyy shared. Note that their point is correct: `snapshot.data` will *never* be null, but `snapshot.data!.exists` indicates whether a document was loaded from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have shared the code file link as well. I have tried these but query snapshot have no function named "exists".

Comment: Click here for the code : [Accounts.Dart](https://github.com/sheikh-tabarak/account-book/blob/main/lib/Screens/Accounts/Accounts.dart)

Comment: Don't provide the code in a link please. Instead edit your question and add an update at the bottom with the code where you use `snapshot.data!.exists` to check if the document exists as Gwhyyy explained in their answer.